# how to get youtube info from google login oauth

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth

I already get access token and google userid from the oauth result
So now, how can I read the youtube related info?

axios to https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&mine=true&key=[PUT_YOUR_KEY] seems to failed

I use adonisjs (one of nodejs framework)

```
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&mine=true&key=" + [API_KEY];
console.log(url);

var AuthStr = "Bearer ".concat(authGoogle.getAccessToken());
console.log(AuthStr);


        await axios
            .post(url, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: AuthStr
                }
            })
            .then(function(message) {
                console.log(message);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log('logging error: ');
                console.log(error);
            });
```

I got 'logging error', but not even any messaged returned from the url

Comment: Remove key if you are sending the authorization token.   Also Have you considered using googles library?   https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples#authorizing-and-making-authorized-requests

Comment: I have removed the key also, and including access token as Bearer auth only but still no luck, i will dig somewhere else again

Comment: And your sure this is a valid access token please include your authentication code.

Comment: I use adonis JS framework which has its adonis-ally. Please check : https://github.com/adonisjs/adonis-ally/blob/develop/src/Drivers/Google.js

Comment: is the access token different?